The number of $3$- digit odd numbers, whose sum of digits is a multiple of $7$
The number of $3$- digit odd numbers, whose sum of digits is a multiple of $7$
My solution: Let Number as $xyz$ and $x+y+z=7k$, where $k=0,1,2,3$ where $z\in\{1,3,5,7,9\}, x\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}, y\in\{0,1,2,....,9\}$
Generating function for above linear equation is $(x+x^2+x^3+...+x^9)(1+x+x^2+....+x^9)(x+x^3+x^5+x^7+x^9)$
Hence coefficient of $x^{7k}$ in above generating function is
$0$ when $k=0$,
$12$ when $k=1$,
$35$ when $k=2$,
$16$ when $k=3$
Hence final answer is $63$
My doubt: Is there any other way to solve this?

"Better" is a subjective term. What I find better and what you find better will almost certainly differ. Are there other ways of solving this? Obviously yes. Are any of them better? That, only you can answer.

This is basically the same as the generating function method.
Let's form a Markov chain with states $0,1,\dots, 6$ for each residue class $\mod 7$. (Well not exactly a Markov chain since we don't have probabilities but the counts.) We need to adjust the first and last transitions accordingly (non-zero digits and odd digits), so for $n$ digit numbers the answer is the $1,1$-entry of the matrix
$$
\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrr}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrr}
2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2
\end{array}\right)^{n-2}
\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrr}
1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\
2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right)
$$
If we consider the generating polynomial to be in $\mathbb Q[x]/\langle x^7-1 \rangle$ I think this is exactly equivalent to the GF calculation.

Another way to calculate the GF product:
$$
g(x) = (x+x^2+\dots+x^9)(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^9)^{n-2}(x+x^3+x^5+x^7+x^9) \\
= \frac{x^2(1-x^9)(1-x^{10})^{n-1}}{(1-x)^{n-1}(1-x^2)} \\
= \frac{x^2(1-x^9)(1-x^{10})^{n-1}}{(1-x)^{n}(1+x)} \\
= p(x)\frac{ (1-x^{10})^{n-2}}{(1-x)^{n}}\\
$$
for the prefactor
$$
p(x) =  x^2(1-x^9) \frac{1-x^{10}}{1+x} = -x^{11} + \sum_{a=2}^{20} (-x)^a
$$
Now we can expand the numerator of $g$ by binomial theorem. (Let's not expand the denominator, but then extract the coefficient from it)
$$
g(x) = p(x) \sum_{a=0}^{n-2} \binom{n-2}{a}(-x^{10})^a \frac{1}{(1-x)^{n-1}}
$$
And so the answer is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty [x^{7k}] g(x) \\
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^{n-2} \binom{n-2}{j} (-1)^j \left(  -\binom{n-1+7k-10j-11}{n-1} + \sum_{a=2}^{20} (-1)^a \binom{n-1+7k-10j-a}{n-1}  \right)
$$
Maybe this could be simplified further with some identity. But like this it's a double sum in $n$ (since $k$ needs to go only up to, what $2n$?, btw how to see that from the formula??, how does it cancel out when $k$ is big, I'm not seeing it immediately).
Anyway, the matrix method is faster for large $n$, since we can do fast exponentiation. (Albeit the numbers do get huge.)
